# Kendo Treeview with remote datasource issue

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have the following code for my treeview. Everything is ok. I can use my tree: expand, collapse, drag items. But when I call 'select' event for any node I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'dataItem' of undefined"

on the line

`var data = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(e.node);`

Any ideas how to solve that? How can I access `data("kendoTreeView")` of my tree? I've tried to get it on `endRequest` event of datasource but it doesn't work.

```
var jsonUrl = "/admin/adminmenu/adminmenujson";
    adminMenu = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: jsonUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                children: "items"
            }
        }
    });

    var tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        name: "Admin Menu",
        expanded: true,
        loadOnDemand: false,
        dragAndDrop: true,
        dataSource: kendo.observableHierarchy(adminMenu),
        template: "#= item.name #  <input type='hidden' class='data_id' value='#=item.id#'>",
        select: function(e) {
            var data = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(e.node);
            console.log(data.id);
        }
    }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tree control in question but `$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView")` is `null` - so put a breakpoint on that line in your javascript debugger (Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools/etc) and examine `$("#treeview").data` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `select` handler as:

```
select      : function (e) {
    var data = this.dataItem(e.node);
    console.log(data.id);
}
```

Since `this` in the context of the `select` handler is the `tree`.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MLdeH/

**NOTE:** Try just removing `name: "Admin Menu",` it will also work!!!

Comment: can you help me with a create node button?

Comment: What is the problem with create button? What do you want to create? How does this relate with the original question?

Comment: i have a such code which does nothing `$("#append").click(function () {
             var treeView = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView().data("kendoTreeView");
             console.log(treeView)
             var selectedNode = treeView.select();
             console.log(selectedNode)

             if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
                 selectedNode = null;
             }

             selectedNode.append({
                 text: "test_node"
             }, selectedNode);
        });`

Comment: sorry, I got it. I have to do like `treeView.append(...` instead of `selectedNode.append(..` Thank you for patient and answering my strange questions)